# Proving a Condition of Convergence of a Sequence in a Metric Space

Tags: convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

### Question

Let $(M,d)$ be a metric space, such that $M = R_+^{*k} = (0,\infty) \times (0,\infty) \times ... \times(0,\infty)$ and $d(x,y) = d((x^1,x^2,...,x^k),(y^1,y^2,...,y^k)) = ||(x^1,x^2,...,x^{k-1})-(y^1,y^2,...,y^{k-1})|| + \bigg|\dfrac{1}{x^k} - \dfrac{1}{y^k}\bigg|$.

Prove that $x_n \rightarrow \bar x \iff \forall i \in\{1,2,...,k\}, x_n^i \rightarrow \bar x^i$

### What I've done so far

$(\implies)$

Let $(x_n)_{n \in N} \subset M; x_n \rightarrow \bar x$.

For $i \in \{1,...,k-1\}$, we have that $|x_n^i - \bar x^i| \leq d(x_n,\bar x)$.

So, from $x_n \rightarrow \bar x$, we have that: $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists n_0 \in N; n>n_o \implies d(x_n,\bar x) < \epsilon$.

Since $|x_n^i - \bar x^i| \leq d(x_n,\bar x)$, we can write that: $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists n_0 \in N; n>n_o \implies |x_n^i - \bar x^i| < \epsilon$. So it's clear that $x_n^i \rightarrow \bar x^i.$

Now suppose, by contradiction, that $x_n^k \nrightarrow \bar x^k$. It is: $\exists \epsilon > 0, \forall n_0 \in N, \exists n \in N; n > n_0 \land |x_n^k - \bar x^k| > \epsilon$

Now I'm stuck.

### What I know

I know I need to find a way to prove that $|x_n^k - \bar x^k| > \epsilon \implies \bigg|\dfrac{1}{x_n^k} - \dfrac{1}{\bar x^k}\bigg| > \delta$, for some $\delta > 0$. And then I can use it to prove that if $x_n^k \nrightarrow \bar x^k$ then $\exists \delta > 0, \forall n_0 \in N, \exists n_* \in N; n_*>n_o \land d(x_n,\bar x) > \delta$

I'm still working on the $(\Longleftarrow)$ part of proof.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: For both parts you only need the following:

Lemma

Let $t,t_1,t_2,... \in (0,\infty)$. Then $t_n \to t$ iff $\frac  1{t_n} \to \frac 1 t$.

Proof: The map $g: (0,\infty) \to (0,\infty)$ defined by $g(t)=\frac1  t$ is a homemorphism (and it is its own inverse!). Hence $t_n \to t$ iff $g(t_n) \to g(t)$.